# R takes the wrong values in a function

Tags: r, function

I have the following code, which worked up until now.

```
     df %>% 
      group_by(id) %>% 
      filter(between(date, start_date, start_date + 3)) %>%
      mutate(Product = accumulate(1 + ret, `*`)) %>%
      as.data.frame() %>% 
      right_join(df) %>% 
      arrange(desc(id), date)

     id       date   start_date    ret  Product
1 12055 2001-08-02   2001-08-03 1.0246       NA
2 12055 2001-08-03   2001-08-03 1.1230 1.123000
3 12055 2001-08-04   2001-08-03 0.9940 1.116262
4 11033 2001-08-02   2001-08-05 1.0200       NA
5 11033 2001-08-03   2001-08-05 0.9970       NA
6 11033 2001-08-04   2001-08-05 0.9490       NA
7 11033 2001-08-05   2001-08-05 1.0480 1.048000
8 11033 2001-08-06   2001-08-05 1.0600 1.110880
9 11033 2001-08-07   2001-08-05 1.0020 1.113102
```

But now I am getting weird results as in that the following code gives me the mathematically wrong product.

```
mutate(ret2 = accumulate(1 + ret1, `*`))
```

I tested the following code:

```
df$Productx <- accumulate(1 + df$ret, `*`)
```

and that worked fine.

Do you guys have an idea of what might be wrong with the embedded version at the top?

Thanks!

Comment: The embedded version works on a grouped data.frame while `df$Productx <- accumulate(1 + df$ret,'*')` uses the data.frame as is. Further, in your embedded code you use `ret1` whereas the other Code part uses `df$ret`.

Comment: Thanks! But solved the issue. Apparently, I have to install the packages 'plyr' after 'dply'.